# What software issues are caused by power failure shutdowns?

Tags: windows-7, windows, battery, power

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is unplugging the power from a PC in standby or in normal mode bad for it?](https://superuser.com/questions/110055/is-unplugging-the-power-from-a-pc-in-standby-or-in-normal-mode-bad-for-it)

I have a laptop that had a failing battery. The battery life was very bad and if I accidentally left my laptop in sleep mode without being plugged, the battery will completely drain before the laptop could wake up and go into hibernate mode. The laptop would take very long to reboot after this but that is expected. I am also experiencing more strange software issues and long reboots after a normal shutdown.

What kind of issues would be expected by this kind of hard reboot caused by a power failure. I would expect disk issues, so I am running chkdsk and disk defragmentation. What other things should I check?

Comment: It really depends on what you have running.  Any files that are being written can potentially go screwy.  Any software that has to write to a file on closing and doesn't close properly can go screwy.  (The same with filetypes that the program locks when they're open, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is unplugging the power from a PC in standby or in normal mode bad for it?](http://superuser.com/questions/110055/is-unplugging-the-power-from-a-pc-in-standby-or-in-normal-mode-bad-for-it), specifically see [This Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/110055/is-unplugging-the-power-from-a-pc-in-standby-or-in-normal-mode-bad-for-it/110096#110096) for reasons as to _Why_ it's bad.

Comment: I understand the high level concepts of what can go wrong but not how to detect specific issues or fix them.