# Will unplugging/replugging the power cable on a powered off computer damage the hardware components?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I just removed the cable connected to my computer and switched off the power supply switch. Then I opened the computer case in the side just to gently blow some air to get the dust out. But after just about less than 5 minutes after blowing some air, I closed the CPU and plugged back the power cable and turned on the switch.

But what I noticed was that my keyboard had "Num Lock" "Caps Lock" and "Scroll Lock" lights all lit up even if I did not press the power button in the computer yet. It disappeared as soon as I turned on my computer. When I got to the desktop I got an error: "Default Radeon WattMan settings has been restored due to unexpected system failure" but nothing seems to be wrong. I am just wondering why it never appears except for the time I unplug the power cable and turn off the power switch just now. Is there damage to the computer if you keep removing the power chord? Does it get a power surge or get shocked?

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/110055/302907

Comment: @Anaksunaman However my computer was completely off when I unplugged it and not in some standby/hibernation mode/sleep mode. I believe the other question was indicating if it was unplugged randomly if it was turned on? I am not sure. Or does it mean that anytime you want to move your computer elsewhere and disconnect the power chord, there is some surge and risk damaging components so it is better to not keep moving your computer around and keep it in one place?

Comment: Are you definitely shutting down fully? It may not matter, but is fast-start enabled or disabled? Are you switching off at the wall socket before removing the plug/cable? (I also don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question)

Comment: If the PC was in a lower level sleep state ([S0 - S3](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/63346-sleep-states-available-your-windows-10-pc.html)), and it's not a laptop, unplugging the PC is effectively a dirty shutdown, however if the system is in a higher-level sleep state (S4 - S5), unplugging the PC has no effect since RAM is no longer in use _(RAM requires voltage)_.  If Windows has a dirty power off, it should be rebooted at the login screen (if the option is available), else as soon as the user logs in.

Comment: @Smock Our wallsockets here have no switch off just plug/plug out. Also for `fast-start` I don't know what that is but I have to always press the power button and pressing the keyboard/mouse will not do anything if it's off. Before plugging out I just pressed the "Shut down" in windows and just wait for the fans to stop running and the computer has no noise and monitor to go completely out of signal

Comment: @JW0914 No idea about the states but I just shut down from windows and make sure everything seems died down (fans, monitor, and any sort of life from the PC)

Comment: @Pherdindy Shutting down the PC isn't always an actual full shutdown if Fast Startup is enabled in the BIOS/UEFI firmware or in the Power options.  That being said, if Fast Startup is not enabled, and shut down is selected, the PC should be in state G3 (mechanical off)